# How the compiler make the link between basic ANSI C type and the processor selected

Tags: c, types, compiler-construction, arm, processor

For each processor (Cortex M, Cortex 5), the compiler must know what is the  data size associated to `unsigned char`, `integer`, `short`, .......

Please could you help me to understand how this choice is done?

Comment: There's a source file in the compiler with a table, roughly speaking.

Comment: You basically tell the compiler by specifying which architecture you want to compile for. That points it to header files and such that define these things.

Comment: some human tells the compiler their choice, the author of the compiler or the person that ported the compiler to that architecture.  etc.  Very much compiler specific not architecture specific and can vary at any time with any new release of a compiler or some compilers might even have command line options to vary these definitions.

Comment: if you were there to experience the 16 to 32 bit change in the world (x86) then you saw the int change from 16 to 32 bits.  But unsigned long was 32 bits so many folks adopted unsigned long for a consistent 32 bit variable that ported across 16 and 32 bit compilers.  We are still in the 32 to 64 bit transition and the int did not change but the long did so all that code that used unsigned long to avoid change, was now hit with a change.  stdint tries to solve this but here again some human made that file too to match the compiler

Comment: both the compiler and stdint headers have to be maintained in parallel.  stdint was basically a hack to solve the problem you are perhaps falling into.  Note that the term byte doesnt mean 8 bits, 9 bits used to make a lot more sense when folks though in terms of octal.  Nothing dictates a byte has to be 8 bits (from one architecture to another) nor does it dictate a char has to be a byte, nor does it dictate an int has to be the size of a register or the size of the address bus.  This is your job as a programmer to check your code for the platform or use habits that happen to be more portable

Answer (score 0):

> Please could you help me to understand how this choice is done?

Guessing compiler we are talking is a C one.

First we have the spec for C language, see wiki article [C data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types). But then C spec gives some flexibility to implementer...

`int` is architecture's word. A word is architecture's almost atomic size of processing. For legacy ARM this is 32-bit, think as architecture has 32-bit registers.

`char` is shortest bit string. Nowadays you can't get less than 8, and almost all architectures let you play with 8. 8 is good because it matches with ASCII, so you get efficient support from architecture to play ASCII strings.

`short` helps when your architecture can do operations on 16-bit values, and  `long` is good for 64-bit.

`signed` / `unsigned`isn't really related to this, as in when some bit string is used as signed it gets reduced in upper limit of what it can represent.